# Unable to load the specified metadata resource && the assembly specified does not exist in the assemblies enumration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, metadata, entitydatasource

I'm facing this error while using EntityDataSource 
[image]

Solutions I've tried 
1- Built the solution 'ctrl + shift + B' 
2- In web config file changed the resources 
From

```
"metadata=
     res://*/GreenCityModel.csdl|
     res://*/GreenCityModel.ssdl|
     res://*/GreenCityModel.msl;provider=
```

To

```
"metadata=
     res://GreenCityChiniotWeb/GreenCityModel.csdl|
     res://GreenCityChiniotWeb/GreenCityModel.ssdl|
     res://GreenCityChiniotWeb/GreenCityModel.msl;provider=
```

"GreenCityChiniotWeb" is my correct assembly name which I'm pretty sure.
after applying this solution error slightly changed
[image]

3rd solution I tried was so called worst case by using only *

```
<add name="GreenCityChinyotDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=
    res://*/;provider= <!-- ... -->
```

than there were no errors thrown, but the "DefaultContainerName:" combobox remained empty
[image]

what else can i try?

Comment: Do you have an .EDMX file, and what is its build-action?

Comment: yes there is a GreenCityModel.EDMX in my solution.
and what do you mean by build-action i don't understand this! 

For acknowledged I'm using stored procedures to fill grids and insertion into tables in code and that is working perfect with same connection string and edmx

Comment: Click on the Edmx and then look at (open) the properties window. The Build action should be EntityDeploy

Comment: Yes the Build action is EntityDeploy